# Page Reference is not Working in Lightning

Tags: visualforce

Here is my requirement, to upload the digital Signature against the Account as Notes and Attachment. on Click of "Save Signature", In Salesforce1 after saving the signature,not redirecting to Salesforce1 detail screen.In Classic Redirection is Working fine on click of "Save Signature".Need help,Thanks in advance.

```
public with sharing class ehsSignatureExtensionController {

private final Account ehs;
private static String signatureBody;
public static Boolean showSubmit{get; set;}
public static Boolean showMesg{get; set;}

public ehsSignatureExtensionController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    ehs = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    showSubmit = true;
    showMesg = false;

}

@RemoteAction 
public static RemoteSaveResult saveSignature(Id ehsId, String signatureBody) {
signatureBody = signatureBody;
showSubmit = false;
    RemoteSaveResult newResult = new RemoteSaveResult();
    if( signatureBody != null && signatureBody != ''){
    Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId=ehsId, name='Signature.png', ContentType='image/png', Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(signatureBody));
    Database.saveResult result = Database.insert(a,false);
    newResult.success = result.isSuccess();
    newResult.attachmentId = a.Id;
    newResult.errorMessage = result.isSuccess()?'':result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
        //return new PageReference('/'+a.id);
    return newResult;
    }else {
    showMesg = true;
    return null;
    }

}

public class RemoteSaveResult {
    public Boolean success;
    public Id attachmentId;
    public String errorMessage;
}

public pageReference cancel(){

    return new PageReference('/'+ehs.id);
}
public static String Clear(){
signatureBody='';
return null;
}
}

function handleResult(result,event) {
    if(result.success) {
       //<!-- window.top.location.href='/'+ehsId; -->
       this.parent.location.href='/'+ehsId;

       <!--pageRedirection(ehsId);-->
    } else {
        alert('Error: '+result.errorMessage);
    }
}

<apex:commandButton value="Save Signature" onclick="saveSignature();return false;" styleClass="button"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to conditionally use different navigation theme based on theme as below:

```
function handleResult(result,event) {
    if(result.success) {
        //<!-- window.top.location.href='/'+ehsId; -->
        if({!$User.UIThemeDisplayed} == 'Theme3')
            this.parent.location.href='/'+ehsId;
        else if({!$User.UIThemeDisplayed} == 'Theme4d') {
            if((typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && 
                (!!sforce.one)) {
                sforce.one.navigateToSObject(ehsId);
            }
        }

        <!--pageRedirection(ehsId);-->
    } else {
        alert('Error: '+result.errorMessage);
    }
}
```